# creating uneven boundries for the div element

Tags: html, css

I want to create the class which will reshape the element. I am not sure it is possible or not with only pure css. But a class to the image element will transform the image to the shape given below.

```
<style>
.reshape{
//what to put inside here?
}
</style>
<img class='reshape'>
```

[image: The shape required]

If it is not possible with pure css, is there any alternate solution for the same? Thank's in advance.

Comment: border-radius, check its syntaxe and effects and all sorts of rounded shapes it can produce (including this of yours )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from experimenting with border-radius:

```
.reshape{
  border-radius:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: border-radius will try to create the pure curve. instead of uneven curve.

Comment: What does it mean "uneven curve" in this case? Considering that you can define corner radii independently.

Comment: unfortunately, the individual border radius wont working for the image

Comment: yah it working now i messed up with comments :) thank's